# sync Iphone6 IOs9 with ubunutu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, windows, iphone

I have iphone6 with IOS9(newest one) Can you tell me how to sync music with my PC which uses Ubuntu 14.04lts 64bit. Please help, because I love ubuntu, but it's very sad for me that I can't sync my phone with PC. I don't want to return to Win !!!

Answer (score 2):

It *is* sad, but this is actually Apple's doing. Ubuntu has been able to sync to iDevices for quite some time, via `libimobiledevice`. However, most new versions of iOS use a new database that doesn't work with Linux. (According to tech support, that was intentional on Apple's part.)

Assuming you have `libimobiledevice` installed, you can check if your Apple device is compatible. Plug it into your computer, and then run the following in the Terminal.

```
$ ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.iTunes -k DBVersion
```

If that reports a version greater than 4, unfortunately, iTunes is your only option. [That or taking your iDevice out to a firing range for some target practice and getting an Android. That works too.]

---

**Workaround:** I am able to "sync" music with my iPod Touch using [Google Play Music](http://play.google.com/music). It's actually pretty slick, and less annoying than iTunes ever was - no cords or tethering required!

Install the free Google Play Music app on your iDevice and pair it with your Google account. Then install [Google Music Manager](https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=0#/manager) on your Ubuntu computer and have it monitor your music folder. It will upload all of your music to the cloud (which stores up to 50,000 songs for free).

You can play all your music, even Ogg Vorbis, via the internet on your iDevice with the app, and you can select individual tracks to store offline on the mobile device.

Side benefits: you can play your entire music library online with a web browser ([play.google.com/music](http://play.google.com/music)) you can buy tracks directly from Google Play, and the paid version works just like Spotify (stream anything). Plus, it's a handy backup for your music in case your computer ever dies.

You'll never need Apple Music or iTunes again. :P

Comment: any news about version 5? Today i bought iPad mini 2, now 6 hours of googling and,... to get it syncs but without luck. banshee syncs my music, its stored on phone memory, but the "Music" app does not detect new music, even when i did turning on/of device or doing "hard" restart..

Comment: Latest news is no news, unfortunately. It is not possible at this time. Watch the [libimobiledevice website](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) for the latest. Scroll down to the big colored table of features - music sync is the third row down.

Comment: @ErikKubica, see my workaround.